# "Smiled at me" vs. "smiled to me"

Tags: prepositions

I searched for the following two expressions and came across both being used in various places.

> She **smiled at me** at the grocery store.
>
> She **smiled to me** at the grocery store.

What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Smile at" is more common, so saying "smile to" is a way to indicate a more "decisive" smile, or intent to communicate via the smile.

I do not understand why others say "to" is incorrect here. It is less common, to be sure, but that does not make it incorrect. You can wave to a crowd, or wave at a crowd...but just because we say "wave to" more often, that does not make "wave at" incorrect.

Comment: Perhaps it is ok, but I couldn't find any reference to "smile to" in a dictionary.

Comment: +1: My very thoughts. Just to prove the point, here are over 2000 written instances of ["smiled to the crowd"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22smiled+to+the+crowd%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, however, "smiled at the crowd" has 51k written instances vs. "smiled to the crowd" has 2k (Google Books UK). And all these numbers are sort of meaningless, good as something to start with. You need to manually go through those examples, at least the first hundred. Year? Type of text/genre? Published where? Written by who etc.

Comment: Well put. This is yet another issue that has more to do with style and commonality than strict correctness. My view is that the connotation should be presented as to what level of intimacy is present, although this probably doesn't hold up in all common use cases. Some examples: I whisper to the woman, having approached her after winking at her. I am talking to the mail carrier, having waved at him, and hearing him holler at me. "To" seems like the more direct, intimate, or active of the two, although I could be wrong, and phonetics and habits are probably factors.

Comment: @Alex B.: Such information might be enlightening, but the mere fact that it's not uncommon (albeit less common than *"at"*) shows *"to"*it is at least "acceptable" to many - which is all I intended to convey. The idea that only one preposition is "correct" is untenable, to my mind.

Answer (score 2):

Although I agree that "smiled **to** me" does get said sometimes, "smiled **at** me" is the technically correct version. Usage reflects this, as shown in this NGram shows:

[image]

Also, Dictionary.com [does not have an entry for "smiled to", only "smiled at"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/smile).

I wonder if "smile **to**" was invented as a gentler sounding form of "smile **at**", in the same way that "talk **to**" is gentler and less-aggressive than "talk **at**".

Comment: +1 for actual data, and don't forget, "smile to" can also mean "smile because":  "The proud father smiled to hear his daughter praised by strangers."

Comment: Also, you can smile to yourself.

Comment: And fortune or the gods smile on you.

Comment: And what does "technically correct" mean?

Comment: @Malvolio: That’s a different *to*, though.

Comment: -1 because I feel more strongly than @colin that bandying around statements like *"smiled at me" is the technically correct version* is completely unjustified. There may be some element of rationale in the fact that idiomatically *"smiled to me"* tends to be avoided, but that certainly doesn't make the alternative version "technically correct" - it's just "more common".

Comment: @ColinFine -- technically correct is [the best kind of correct](http://theinfosphere.org/images/thumb/9/9f/Number_1.0.png/180px-Number_1.0.png)!

Comment: @Malvolio Somebody should buy this guy a pizza! --SB, (typing with his boxing gloves on)

Comment: @FumbleFinger I thought "smiled to" was not correct because it was not in any of the dictionaries I looked at. If I'm wrong, I'll change it. End of. (I clearly stated that above, so not sure why you say it is "completely unjustified".)

Comment: @Colin I couldn't think of a better phrase than "technically correct" to describe how I see it. "Smiled to" gets used sometimes, and it is debatable whether it is acceptable. But "smiled at" is clearly right.

Comment: @Urbycoz: I can only repeat that to me at least, *"technically correct"* means there's some grammatical rule specifying that *"smiled at"* is "valid", and that by implication *"smiled **on**"* is somehow "invalid". This is not the case - it just so happens that one preposition is more common than the other in this exact context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I understand you have your opinion on this. But you're ignoring what I've actually said. I would expect "smile to" (guess that's what you meant to write) to be listed in the dictionary if it is correct. I don't mind you disagreeing, but please can you try to back it up.

Answer (score 2):

I searched the BNC, and here are the results.

Ignoring cases like "smile to verb", "smile to oneself" or "smile to the side", I've been able to find only 4 examples of "smile to somebody".

In COCA, there are 15 examples only. I'd say it's pretty rare.

The OED does say that smile to somebody is possible, cf. "2a. To look *on*, *upon*, *at*, or *to* a person with a smile or pleasant expression. Also with advs., as *back*, *down*, *over*, *up*."

1749   T. Smollett tr. A. R. Le Sage Gil Blas IV. xii. xiii. 223   At these words of my god-daughter, I smiled to her father.

Now, there is another interesting expression, "to smile at/for/to the cameras".

Answer (score 0):

The second is not correct. I'm not sure what the technical term for it is, but smiling doesn't take an object - saying "she smiled at me" is like saying "she sat to me" or "she ate to me". It doesn't make sense. To a lesser extent, any expression is the same - you can frown *at* someone, but you can't frown *to* someone.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this link](http://esl.about.com/od/grammarintermediate/a/prepositions_of_movement.htm), one should use "at" with static, non-movement verbs and "to" with verbs of movement.  Hence, "she smiled at me" and then she "waved to me".

Comment: Nice idea, but I'm not convinced that link is relevant - it's about the distinction between *He stayed **at** home* and *He went **to** work*. If the "rule" were generally applicable, we should expect *"He spoke **at** me"* to e more common than *"He spoke **to** me"*, but clearly this isn't the case.

Answer (score 0):

"Smiled at me" seems to be the right choice. "Smiled to me" is awkward.